# Jquery code better written/optimized?

Tags: jquery, optimization

I'm just wondering as all 3 do the same thing just to different id's can it be better written/optimized?

```
$('#top_menu,#commun_links,#q_links').hide();

$('#top_menu_toggle').click(function () {
   $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Menu' ? '- Menu' : '+ Menu');
   $('#top_menu').slideToggle('slow').css({'display' : 'block'});
   return false;
});

$('#commun').click(function () {
   $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Community' ? '- Community' : '+ Community');
   $('#commun_links').slideToggle('slow');
   return false;
});

$('#qnav').click(function () {
   $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Quick Links' ? '- Quick Links' : '+ Quick Links');
   $('#q_links').slideToggle('slow');
   return false;
});
```

As usual all help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a function which will bind everything, parametrize it so you can pass where you want to listen for the click, what element you want to slideToggle and label you want to set on the button.

```
function bindClick(click_tgt, rel_el, label) {

   $(click_tgt).click(function () {
      $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ ' + label ? '- ' + label : '+ ' + label);
      $(rel_el).slideToggle('slow').css({'display' : 'block'});
      return false;
   });
}

$('#top_menu,#commun_links,#q_links').hide();

bindClick('#top_menu_toggle', '#top_menu', 'Menu');
bindClick('#commun', '#commun_links', 'Community');
bindClick('#qnav', '#q_links', 'Quick Links');
```

And name it whatever suits you best :)

Comment: hide line has an extra ' that needs to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the markup is made up of links

```
<a class='menu' href='#' data-label='Menu'>Menu</a>
<ul class='items'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<a href='#' data-label='Community'>Community</a>
<ul class='items'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<a href='#' data-label='Quick Links'>Quick Links</a>
<ul class='items'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

$('.items').hide();
$('.menu').click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var label = $this.data('label');
   $this.text($this.text() == '+ ' + label ? '- ' + label: '+ ' + label);
   $this.next('ul:first').slideToggle('slow');
   return false;
});
```

You can make this even better by using a nested UL>LI style

Answer (score 0):

I have optimized complete package for you....You might be interested.

Check this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPnam/2/) Link

**Considering HTML**

```
<div divtotog="top_menu" class="tog" tex="Menu">+ Menu</div>
<div divtotog="commun_links" class="tog" tex="Community">+ Community</div>
<div divtotog="q_links" class="tog" tex="Quick Links">+ Quick Links</div>

<br>
<div id="top_menu" style="display:none;">top_menu</div>
<br>
<div id="commun_links" style="display:none;">commun_links</div>
<br>
<div id="q_links" style="display:none;">q_links</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.tog').click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).attr("tex");
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ '+txt ? '- '+txt : '+ '+txt);
    $("#"+$(this).attr("divtotog")).slideToggle('slow').css({'display' : 'block'});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding a var be better? ... var txt = $(this).attr("tex");